# Ввод строки с пробелами C++

Tags: c++, строки

В общем есть функция, в которой идет ввод `string`-строки через `std::getline();`
Вызывая эту функцию несколько раз подряд, первая строка записывается пустой, затем идет ввод остальных.
Использовал `std::cin.ignore();`, но происходит другая ситуация - Первая строка записывается как нужно, а в остальных пропадает первая буква.

Как это правильно сделать?
Спасибо.

Comment: MCVE приводите, пока - вопрос unclear.

Answer (score -1):

Ну, если первая строка пустая, то можно сделать так:

```
int scan (bool isscan)
{
   string a = "";
   if (isscan == true)
      a.getline (cin);
   return a;
}
```